# Horizontal Bullets Showing In jQuery UI Tabs (IE 8 Only)

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery-ui-tabs

I'm getting a weird bullet in IE 8 on jQuery tabs.  It's showing as the image displays below.  The bullet disappears if I click on the tab.  Can anyone help?  Thanks.

[image]

Comment: I can confirm the problem on IE11 as well. Demo (with fix instructions based on @Jerzy Zawadzki's answer): https://jsfiddle.net/zohalexix/pahmvxwk/2/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

maybe those are from some of yours `LI`?

try set `list-style-type:none` for this `UL`

Comment: @JeffBorden I have the same problem but unfortunately this fix did not work, I added `list-style-type:none` to the `.ui-tabs-nav` which is the UL but the bullet points still show up. Any ideas?

Comment: @OneTwo I had the same problem. Solved it by adding the style directly to the `ul` instead of the `.ui-tabs-nav`.

Answer (score 1):

I can't explain why, but the following style for the ul did the trick for me:

```
list-style-position: inside;
list-style-type: none;
```

('list-style-type:none' alone didn't help.)